# Does React always check the whole tree?

Tags: reactjs

When a component is updated by calling setState, does React run the diffing algorithm on the whole DOM tree, or only on the part of it that belongs to the updated component?

For example, if I have 10000 components in my app and call setState in a component that has no children (it's a leaf of the tree), will React go through the whole large DOM tree (which would be slow) or only the DOM tree generated by the component (which would be a lot faster)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, React will not go through the whole tree when you called setState only on a leaf node.

On call of setState, react will only re-render the component (tree node) for which setState was called on and any components (nodes) which are children. It should be noted that React will only update the DOM if there is actually a change to be represented from the call to setState.

Vjeux, one of the members of the React team, wrote a good blog post detailing how the react diff algorithm works, and how it works when you call setState. Here is the [link](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2013/diff/).

Comment: Its important to understand that when you call setState on a component, all of its sub trees components will be re rendered. To avoid this performance implication, we need to intelligently use ` boolean shouldComponentUpdate(object nextProps, object nextState) `

Comment: This is a good point and it's important to understand that setState can have a large effect if you are calling it higher up in the tree and passing that state down multiple levels through props. I like this [advanced performance link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html) which describes the strategy of using shouldComponentUpdate you detailed above.

Comment: Also, although it is more of an advanced topic, using [immutable data structures](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) and passing those down as props can have big win on performance especially in the shouldComponentUpdate method.