# What is the entry point for the React reconciliation algorithm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get a firmer grasp on some React internals. I understand that, at a high level, React works like this:

- It will only re-render components that have changed.
- It will then diff the "old" virtual DOM (before re-rendering) against the "new" virtual DOM (after re-rendering), and patch the real DOM to account for the changes.

My question is about a detail of the process just described (hopefully correctly):

Does the reconciliation process always start *at the app root* (i.e., comparing the old virtual DOM with the new virtual DOM starting from the very top of both trees), or does it somehow know to only diff re-rendered components?

To perhaps make it clearer what I am after, consider this example. Suppose my app is structure like this:

```html
<main id="app">
  <section id="part1">...</section>
  <section id="part2">...</section>
</main>
```

Let's assume that only the "part1" component has been re-rendered. Now, reconciliation starts. Will the reconciliation algorithm only diff "part1", or will it start with the main app component, walking through the whole tree (including "part2")?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696816/does-react-always-check-the-whole-tree/34697047) is very similar to mine, but the accepted answer talks about re-rendering rather than diffing, so it doesn't unambiguously answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the reconciliation process always start at the app root

No, thats impossible. The "new virtual DOM" is what gets returned from a `render()` call (or from calling a functional component), and a Component only rerenders if its state was changed. Therefore as there is only a "new virtual DOM" for the updated elements, reconcilation can only be done on those (it also makes sense to only do as much work as necessary).

Some pseudocode:

```
  const dom = {
     props: {},
     type: App,
     el: document.getElementById("app"),
     children: [{
        type: Child,
        props: {},
        children: [],
     }],
 };

 function reconcile(domNode, update) {
    for(const [i, child] of domNode.children.entries()) {
      // If nothing changed, skip
      if(child.type === update[i].type && child.props === update[i].props)
         continue;
       // Replace the child
       if(child.type !== update[i].type) {
         removeDomNode(child.el);
         addDomNode(update[i]);
         Object.assign(child, update[i]);
         reconcile(child.children, update[i].children); // go on recutsively
       }
       //...
    }

 }

 // Rerender the first Child
 reconcile(dom.children[0], Child());
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot! The pseudocode is very helpful, too.